# Math processing error on Android app with LaTeX pmod

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, mathjax, math-se

Any LaTeX block rendered on the Android app that contains pmod, such as `$2^{36} = 2^{6^2} = (2^6)^2 \equiv (2^2)^2 \pmod {12} \equiv 2^2 \pmod {12}$`, displays as [Math processing error] in red. The Mathematics site is the only site I use/see LaTeX on.

For reference, this is a common command and it renders correctly in MathJax when I view it on the website.

Comment: A new MathJaX was deployed not so long time ago, and if you have some files cached from the old one, you can get this error. I just make sure that you made sure that you emptied the browser/app cache before. (Sorry, I'm not a "smart" guy, maybe what I say is a non-sense for the Android app, then I apologize.)

Comment: I think the Android app ships its own local copy of MathJax.

Comment: The `\pmod` macro uses `\mathchoice` internally, and that requires the `extensions\TeX\mathchoice.js` file.  make sure that hasn't been removed from the MathJax distribution included in your app.  If that's not the problem, it may still be that something is going wrong while that file is being processed.  You could add `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {alert(MathJax.Hub.lastError.mesage)})</script>` before the script that loads MathJax.js to get an alert that indicates the error that cause the problem.

Comment: Still repro'd on v1.0.82 (beta). Example post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38517/in-relatively-simple-words-what-is-an-inverse-limit/38522#38522 (on Math.SE)

Comment: @andrew I actually don't see it there. Scary to think it might not be predictable.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to reproduce this with version 1.0.82 (currently incubating in beta) but we haven't changed our MathJax binaries or settings in a very long time, so for 1.0.83 coming out later today I've gone ahead and updated to MathJax 2.6.