# Why is an SE employee suddenly a per site moderator?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators

I just noticed that (suddenly) an SE employee (Kasra Rahjerdi) shows up as a per site moderator on [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) see https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

While I would not be opposed if he was actually appointed as a mod on the site, it seems more like a bug to me (no appointment date, and no activity on the site).

What's more this also seems to happen on various other sites (not only beta sites), e.g.:

- https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators
- https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators
- https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Kasra, moderator for a day. I guess they will revoke his database access now ;)

Comment: Yes, 64 sites, which are all the sites he has account on, according to [this page](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators). (just search for Kasra)

Comment: Now the Accounts tab on his [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/216645/kasra-rahjerdi) gives an error. Something bad is happening there... :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

An unfortunate side-effect of a user merge (Kasra ended up having two different accounts - this happens every now and then) - his employee user type got reset to a "normal" type so his user was not filtered out from the moderator lists.

This has now been fixed (we fired Kasra and removed his diamond from everywhere). To Kasra - sorry you had to find out this way.

There is still residual mod Kasra on the child metas, due to caching (they pick the list from their parent site and cache it for a bit).

Comment: Poor Kasra, he moves and gets fired.

Comment: What about the poor panda [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/216645/kasra-rahjerdi?tab=accounts)? Also, he still appears on all sites [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators), but guess it's heavily cached.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not getting a panda for [his network account](http://stackexchange.com/users/216645/kasra-rahjerdi). The second list is indeed heavily cached.

Comment: Oh. The accounts tab. Will have to look at that.

Comment: Maybe it gets fixed if you hire him again?

Comment: @rene - if we do hire him back, he can fix his own damn bugs.

Comment: @Oded no error now, but it also says "no accounts found", and I doubt he chose to hide all account. Also, network profile activity is very lacking, and showing only bunch of badges and very old posts. For example [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274585/152859) from a month ago is not [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/216645/kasra-rahjerdi?tab=activity).

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yeah, the network aggregation isn't the best piece of the codebase, and doesn't recover well from merges.

Comment: I see. But will it recover, at some point?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that is a very good question... to which I don't have a good answer... yet.

Comment: Count on me to check it again in 6-8 days... ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - eh. Surely you mean weeks? (please mean weeks)

Comment: *Setting ping clock to 23/03/2016 23:10*

Comment: Still shows up on Code Review Meta http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: @janos - as it does on other child-meta sites, yes.

Comment: `they pick the list from their parent site and cache it for a bit` How long is a bit? Is 3 months "a bit" or should this have been resolved? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279186/193412

Comment: @enderland - if it were caching, as I originally believed, it would have been resolved. There was an underlying issue where clearing mod status on a main site didn't clear the child-meta mod status for employees, which I think was fixed recently. There may still be a few child-metas with lingering accounts, where one would need to de-mod such a user manually.

Comment: @enderland - I cleared up the problem accounts/users across the network.

Comment: @Oded thanks! That will confuse less of our users :-)