# SE employee appearing on the mod list on every per-site meta

Tags: bug, moderators, per-site-meta

<sup>Similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277060/why-is-an-se-employee-suddenly-a-per-site-moderator), but not a duplicate: this is a new issue.</sup>

[Laura](https://stackexchange.com/users/463263/laura), a "product manager at Stack Overflow", has appeared on the moderator lists on various per-site metas:

- [meta SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)
- [meta M&TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)
- [meta Puzzling](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)
- [meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)
- [meta Worldbuilding](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)
- etc.

(Thankfully this time she *doesn't* appear in [the main-site mod list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).)

Another bug in the diamond/moderator/employee parameters?

Comment: Happens on any per-site meta. (for Laura.)

Comment: Laura is no longer working for us and her diamond was removed on all sites, but apparently that didn't propagate to the Meta sites. If I recall correctly, this has happened before when someone else left the company.

Comment: Sad news @animuson and totally worth an answer, IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll let whoever actually fixes it post an answer. This happened yesterday, so I don't think the automated systems are going to pick it up and remove the diamond on their own without a push from someone.

Comment: @animuson So she's likely to stick around on those mod-lists for as long as Kasra has (nearly 6 weeks and counting)?

Comment: Thanks @animuson, looks like the diamond was removed in a rush, she also didn't update her About Me and her Linkedin, hope everything is OK.

Comment: @randal'thor umm... Kasra still work for SE, in his case it was merge going wrong. (old non-employee and non-mod account merged into his main account)

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah something is broken with transferring this information to Meta (or maybe it just doesn't get transferred), so hopefully whatever fixes this will also fix that. Or not, I don't know. They might just get removed manually.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Still, the problem in both cases is a change on main sites which hasn't propagated to the per-site metas. Neither Laura nor Kasra show up on main-site mod lists any more.

Comment: Well, let's hope the devs will take care of this, and @animuson can poke them internally in 6-8 weeks in case this slips through. :)

Comment: It should resolve itself over time, but I'll see about forcing it/reducing that time for future exits.

Comment: @animuson - So you are saying there seems to be an issue linking information between metas? Never heard of that before :P

Comment: @ShadowWizard p.s. Everything is fine. :) I'm sure she'll get around to updating the various bits soon.

Comment: @Adam "It should resolve itself over time" - 6-8 years? Because it is not. And it's just getting worse, Kasra appears again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Where is Kasra appearing? Also, I was dead wrong on the "resolve itself" bit. This does need intervention, just a matter of finding some time to fix it. I'll try to get that in today.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, and Kasra appeared [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), looks like you or Tim fixed it already. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oded fixed the accounts, and we know what the underlying cause is. The good news is that this shouldn't happen again until someone diamonded network-wide has to be undiamonded, so we have some time. ;)

Comment: @AdamLear Cheers! Maybe you or Oded could add an answer to this and/or slap a [tag:status-completed] tag on it?

Comment: @randal'thor I'm waiting till we fix the underlying issue for it.