# Math Processing Error

Tags: bug, design, duplicate-questions, mathjax

Today while voting to close this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080167/geometry-isosceles-triangle-problem-finding-an-inside-angle) as duplicate, the earlier posts were shown with
***[Math Processing Error]*** in red.

I tried in both Windows PC(Chrome) and in Android phone in Full-site mode, both showed the same error.

> In Windows:

[image]

> In Android, Full-site mode

[image]

This has been already asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250360/math-processing-error-on-android-app-with-latex-pmod), marked as `status-completed` but it was in the **Android app** and it's now not available.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: its a math overflow. no doubt about it.